# defined function got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a problem with this line:

```
processed = process(cleaned, lemmatizer=nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer());
```

Why is the unexpected keyword argument popping up?

```
Error: TypeError: process() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lemmatizer'
```

Here is my code:

```
def process(text, filters=nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')):
""" Normalizes case and handles punctuation
Inputs:
    text: str: raw text
    lemmatizer: an instance of a class implementing the lemmatize() method
                (the default argument is of type nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer)
Outputs:
    list(str): tokenized text
"""
lemmatizer=nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer()
word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(text);

lemma_list = [];
for i in word_list:
    if i not in filters:
        try:
            lemma = lemmatizer.lemmatize(i);
            lemma_list.append(str(lemma));
        except:
            pass
return " ".join(lemma_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
#construct filter for processor
file = open("accountant.txt").read().lower()
filters = set(nltk.word_tokenize(file))
filters.update(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
filters = list(filters)

#webcrawling
webContent = []
dataJobs = pd.read_csv("test.csv");
webContent = []
for i in dataJobs["url"]:
    content = webCrawl(i);
    webContent.append(content);

#clean the crawled text
cleaned_list = []
for j in webContent:
        cleaned = extractUseful(j);
        processed = process(cleaned, lemmatizer=nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer());
        cleaned_list.append(processed)

#save to csv
contents = pd.DataFrame({ "Content":webContent, "Cleaned": cleaned_list})
contents.to_csv("testwebcrawled.csv")


dataJobs[['jd']]= cleaned_list
dataJobs.to_csv("test_v2_crawled.csv")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to correct your indentation, and to add the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks. Additionally, Python does not have a line termination character, all the semi-colons `;` are completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only define one keyword argument `filters` in the function signature for `process` (the `def process(...)` line). If the lemmatizer is what you intend to pass as the filter try:

```
processed = process(cleaned, filter=nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer())
```

If you want to be able to pass a lemmatizer as well, you should change your function signature to something like this:

```
def process(text, 
            filters=nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'),
            lemmatizer=nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer()):
```

But note that you only need the `=` and the content that follows it in your function signature if you want the values after the `=` to be passed as the default arguments for these parameters. Otherwise, you can just do:

```
def process(text, filter, lemmatizer):
    ...
```

And call it like:

```
processed = process(cleaned,
                    filter=nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'),
                    lemmatizer=nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer())
```